# SQL Server - count on unique combination from two columns

Tags: sql-server, unique, combinations, multiple-columns

I have the following table in SQL Server:

```
Name1       Name2   Amount

Larry       George  1
Larry       Michael 1
Michael     George  1
Michael     Larry   1
Larry       George  1
George      Larry   1
```

It would be great if someone could provide me a script for getting the following result (which is the first name does not matter e.g. Larry / George = George / Larry):

```
Name_combination  Amount
Larry / George    3
Larry / Michael   2
Michael / George  1
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: Hi Hamlet - I didn't had a clue how to start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatetate Name1 with Name2 when Name1 is < than Name2, or Name2 with Name1 otherwise:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Name1<Name2 THEN Name1 + ' / ' + Name2
                        ELSE Name2 + ' / ' + Name1 END AS Name_combination,
  SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM
  tablename
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN Name1<Name2 THEN Name1 + ' / ' + Name2
                        ELSE Name2 + ' / ' + Name1 END
```

Please see an [example fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1bef5/1).